# Withdrawing from Smart Contract?

Tags: solidity, bsc

Many projects on BSC seems to have pretty much forked SafeMoon with this being a popular one.

For some reason - I see this particular contract storing BNB in the contract address itself. Is there a way to withdraw the BNB in there somehow with the current code layout without adding anything else in? (I don't see a withdraw function, but does seem like there are a few transfer functions).

https://bscscan.com/address/0x75856ea207ce7194e4e65c334bec143d77701e4a#code

For example ^ this one seems to have 32BNB in there.

Answer (score 1):

In Solidity there are 3 ways to transfer Ether from the smart contract to an other address.

1. [address.transfer()](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/develop/units-and-global-variables.html?highlight=transfer#address-related)

2.[address.send()](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/develop/units-and-global-variables.html?highlight=transfer#address-related)

3.[address.call.value().gas()()](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/develop/units-and-global-variables.html?highlight=transfer#address-related)

(4). Calling a payable function of another contract

So, you have to look for 1 of these 4 options in the smart contract code to see if the BNB is withdrawable.

In the `swapETHForTokens` function Ether can be sent to another address

In the `addLiquidity` function Ether can be sent to another address

In the `transferToAddressETH` function Ether can be sent to another address

So, whenever one of these 3 functions is called Ether can be sent away. Seems like it is not possible for anyone to withdraw Ether manually. =-]

Answer (score 0):

Adding one more - but you should not - only in case of emergency.

There is the selfdestruct function that - „kills“ - a smart contract and transfers any remaining funds to an address